# Firebase push notification action url x ANDROID/IOS issue

Tags: angularjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am in a scenario , where I have to implement push notification for an application which is available in both website and mobile (android , ios). While handling the push notification for the website I have used the click Action url property of firebase pushnotification and it is working fine. But this dependency is some how interupting the push notification usage in android and ios. I have used the FCM tester to check this scenario , If I pass in the prop without the Click Action URL the android/ios is working fine in all three modes (background , foreground , killed mode). If I send the notification with the Click Action URL , while clicking on that particular link the application is not opening and working as expected.[image]

Don't know why its happening. The application is working fine as expected if I don't pass the Click Action URL for android/ios , but Click Action URL  is needed for the web pushnotification. I am currently struck at this point , any help will be appreciated , thanks in advance.